# Remote coding in linux from windows

Tags: linux, ubuntu, remote-server, samba

I have a ubuntu machine in the same network with my windows laptop. I have a  Pycharm Community Edition in my windows machine. I want to use the Pycharm in my windows machine to write Python Scripts which I want to run in Python interpreter present in Ubuntu machine. I am having difficulties installing Samba, as a linux newbie. I get the error that says samba.conf not present.Is there any other alternatives?

Comment: Is using vagrant a possibility here?

Comment: @patricksweeney vagrant is not available in community edition of Pycharm.

Comment: You don't really need it to be supported in your IDE though. That being said, I misunderstood your question and didn't realize ubuntu was already on a different machine. carry on!

Answer (score 1):

Don't bother with Samba. You can configure PyCharm to directly upload changed files to a remote server. I.e., when you save locally on your Windows workstation, it can automatically ftp/sftp the file to a pre-configured location on your remote server. See configuration instructions here:

https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/creating-a-remote-server-configuration.html

Answer (score -1):

I used this when I set up my LAMP machine a few years ago:

https://www.howtoforge.com/ubuntu_debian_lamp_server

Comment: how is that relevant?